# embeding more than one song on my webpage

Tags: javascript, html

i have this code im using to play music on my webpage im developing but i am having problems on how to embed or play more that one song..i want when people visit my site they can play music.anyone with an idea on how i can modify this code ??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Welcome to Groundswell </title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#play-bt").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player")[0].play();
            $("#message").text("Music started");
        })

        $("#pause-bt").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
            $("#message").text("Music paused");
        })

        $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
            $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
            $("#audio-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
            $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
        })
    })
</script>
</head>

<body>

<audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="02 - Hillsong - Run.mp3"></audio>
<div id="message"></div>
<a id="play-bt" href="#">Play music</a> | <a id="pause-bt" href="#">Pause music</a> | <a id="stop-bt" href="#">Stop music</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What library do you use?

Comment: Could you not just duplicate the code but with different IDs?

Answer (score 0):

In the script section, add an array of all the song files, then make a function (or two) that will dynamically set the src of your audio element.

```
<script>
var songlist=['02 - Hillsong - Run.mp3','song2.mp3','song_n.mp3'];
var whichsong=0;
var playing=false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#play-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].play();
        playing=true;
        $("#message").text("Music started");
    })

    $("#pause-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        playing=false;
        $("#message").text("Music paused");
    })

    $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        $("#audio-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
        playing=false;
        $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
    })

    $("#next-bt").click(function(){
       $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
       $("#audio-player")[0].src='';
       whichsong++;
       if(whichsong==songlist.length){whichsong=0;}
       $("#audio-player")[0].src=songlist[whichsong];
       if(playing){$("#audio-player")[0].play();}
    })
})
</script>
```

and then add another link for 'Next' with `id="next-bt"` (and you can probably figure out from here how to make the previous button)

Comment: so what do i do to the audio tag remove?or what?

Comment: Leave it, that's what the function then modifies. I'll add to the function later today if you haven't gotten it working

Comment: Well it should work now, there are just some optimizations missing...just put your song titles in that array

Comment: give that a shot, let me know (I went from regular JS to jQuery so it'd match the rest of the stuff you had)

Comment: i tried it but its not working maybe im doing it wrong on the audio tag is this the way its supposed to be? <audio id="audio-player" name="audio-player" src="songlist"></audio>

Comment: Leave it as it was, the jquery will adjust the src for you...BUT, it should have worked when you hit the next button

Comment: this DOES work for me...what browser are you using? mp3 isn't supported in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, maybe worth looking into HTML5 Audio

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp